# Cannot get the FirstPersonControls in three.js working

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, three.js

i'm trying this:

> controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
>
> controls.movementSpeed = 1000;
> controls.lookSpeed = 0.125;
> controls.lookVertical = true;

it didn't work,
From [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft.html#L232) i found out that i need to update the control with time delta:

> var clock = new THREE.Clock();
>
> controls.update( clock.getDelta() );

but I get `undefined is not a function` error for `THREE.Clock()`

can you please point me to working demo/tutorial with FirstPersonControls, or just tell me whats wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried simply calling `controls.update();` (withough passing a delta) ?

I've just tried using the class by copying a bit of code from the misc_sound.html example.
So in init():

```
controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera );

                controls.movementSpeed = 70;
                controls.lookSpeed = 0.05;
                controls.noFly = true;
                controls.lookVertical = false;
```

and in render():

```
controls.update();
```

**Update**

As Todd points out, in newer versions, a delta time argument needs to be supplied:

```
controls.update(delta);
```

Comment: Hey that worked! thanks! got confused by post on similar problem.

Comment: please see [ToddMorrison's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11286753/1888983), if like me you blindly started copy/pasting first :P The call needs `controls.update(delta);`

Answer (score 5):

Please note that in R49, this api now requires the 'delta' on the update call.
The delta needs to be the millisecond displacement since last update, which should be passed out through the requestAnimationFrame callback.

http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/